# Showing that $f(x, y) = (ax + by, cx + dy)$ is injective iff $ad - bc \neq 0$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x, y) = (ax + by, cx + dy)$ for $x, y, a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$. I want to show that $f$ is an injection if and only if $ad - bc \neq 0$.

Here are my current attempts at proving this assertion:

- First, assume $f$ is injective. Now, let $(x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and say that $f(x_0, y_0) = f(x_1, y_1)$. Then we have $ax_0 + by_0 = ax_1 + by_1$ and $cx_0 + dy_0 = cx_1 + dy_1$. Rerranging and adding these equations, we find that $a(x_0 - x_1) + b(y_0 - y_1) + c(x_0 - x_1) + d(y_0 - y_1) = 0$. This is where I am stuck; I cannot see how we get $ad$ or $bc$ out of this equation.
- Conversely, assume $ad - bc \neq 0$. Then $ad \neq bc$, and we have $\frac{a}{c} \neq \frac{b}{d}$. I am also unsure of how to continue from here.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It might be easier to prove the equivalent statement: $f$ is non-injective iff $ad=bc.$

Comment: Your first point was a bad start. You first assume $f$ is injective, ok. But then, taking 2 pairs having the same image by $f$ can be of no help to prove that $ad\ne bc.$ Your second point was slippery: you cannot divide by $cd$ if $c$ or $c$ is $0.$

Comment: Note that $f$ is just left multiplication by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}$ on column vectors. Also, $ad-bc$ is the determinant of that matrix. So, the statement could be proven using linear algebra.

Comment: @AnneBauval How would one go about proving the reverse direction (if $f$ is no-injective, then $ad = bc$)? I'm still stuck on how to use the fact that $f$ is injective besides taking $2$ pairs with the same image by $f$, which, as you said, is of no help in proving that $ad \neq bc$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$
is non-injective, there exist two distinct pairs $(x,y)≠(x′,y′)$
having the same image by $f.$
Let $u:=x−x′,v=y−y′.$
Then, $au+bv=0$
(A) and $cu+dv=0$
(B). $c$A−$a$B
gives $(bc−ad)v=0,$
and $d$A−$b$B
gives $(ad−bc)u=0.$
But $u,v$
are not both $0,$
so $ad=bc.$

Conversely, assume $ad=bc,$ i.e. $f(b,-a)=f(d,-c)=(0,0).$ If one of the four numbers $a,b,c,d$ is $\ne0,$ this gives a non-zero pair having the same image by $f$ as the zero pair (for instance if $a\ne0:$ $(b,-a)\ne(0,0)$ and $f(b,-a)=f(0,0)$). On the other hand, if $a=b=c=d=0,$ $f$ is the zero map hence also non-injective.

Comment: I think using $dA - bB$ yields $adu + bdv - bcu - bdv = 0$, which then allows us to conclude that $u(ad - bc) = 0$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you @ChristopherMiller, 2 misprints corrected.

Comment: Also, for the converse, what if two or four of $a, b, c, d \neq 0$ (three can't happen because if one side equals $0$ the other side must have a $0$)? How do you prove that $(b, -a) \neq (d, -c)$ always then (what if $a = c$ and $b = d$)?

Comment: Actually, the casework works out quite nicely. Never mind.

Comment: @ChristopherMiller What is "the casework"? Nevermind, there is no problem in my converse. I shall add some detail.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative as suggested by Geoffrey Trang.

Observe that $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}^2$ is linear with $\ker f=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2 : \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\end{pmatrix}\}$

$f$ is injective $\iff\ker f=\{0\}\iff \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix} \text{ is invertible}\iff
 \begin{vmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{vmatrix}=0$

Comment: In view of the post, I don't think the questionner is aware of the definitions and theorems used in this answer.

Comment: Right. If the OP knew what any of this meant they wouldn't have asked this question.